# passbook implementation with IOS + updating values via web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, passbook

i am new to IOS. i have to develop an app which supports to something call "passbook". i have searched about it and found that it need some json file and we need to create something with the extension ".pkpass ["fileName.pkpass"]. so i have go through every steps and finally could create a pass as they said and display on the emulator without a problem.

Now i have few problems.

1. When we want to show the card inside our own application ,the apple documents and in some tutorials they said the pkpass file should be inside the xcode project as a resource file. but in reality the card should be fetch from web service. how to do that kind of a thing ?
2. how we do the updates to the card, such as after reading the bar-code  how to change the balance on the card.[i know we have to use a web service, but since the json file is inside the pkpass file how we going to change the value on it?].

how can i do such things with my app ?.in my app there is a card which is capable of paying for coffee. so when card is scanned then the balance should be updated.[i have put a refresh button in the app so that i can call my services and take the new balance and show it.] since this new thing called passbook using pkpass file to generate the card and all , i don't have any idea how to do this.

please help me.i want step by stem instruction. i searched the internet but couldn't find good resources

thank you.

Comment: Have you read the passbook programming guide? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i did.. and i have created a pass too. but for my problems, that document didn't help. :(

Comment: It covers everything you asked in your question.  There is a section with a flow chart on updating a pass.  There is a section on accessing the pass from your app.  For passes most of the coding will be on your server side, not in your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok if i need to do most of the things in server, how can i create the pkpass in my server ? do you have any idea ? please tell me

Comment: You can either write code or you can use a 3rd party service such as http://www.passsource.com  StackOverflow isn't here to write code for you.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok , thank you for your help. but i have something to ask from you. lets say i have created the pkpass file from the service, so in my application i need to download the pkpass to the device and show it ? am i correct ?

Comment: You can either add a pass using the `addPasses` method of the passkit framework, or the user can add a pass to their device using a link in Safari or an email - passes are managed by the pass app on the phone, not by your app